# RTMP + FFMPEG streaming: how do I change a file on the fly?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I use ffmpeg for rtmp streaming for instance with a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 ... rtmp://localhost/stream
```

Sometime I need to replace file.mp4 with new_file.mp4. How do I do that without stutters and stopping the stream? I suppose I can't do sth like that:

```
mv new_file.mp4 file.mp4
```

without killing the ffmpeg process :)

Comment: Tell me please what solution did you find?

Comment: There is a comment in a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740194/ffmpeg-change-file-while-streaming#comment92405820_52740194

Answer (score 0):

Put your ffmpeg inside an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  ffmpeg -i file.mp4 ... rtmp://localhost/stream
done
```

Comment: This does not work, the broadcast will restart every iteration